# how do I install mono runtime on Steam OS?

Tags: linux, mono, debian-based, steamos

from what i understand steam os is a re skinned debian 8

someone had a method using sudo apt-key, that did not work, it says it's missing

I just want to see if I can get help

edit: it's actually based on arch

Comment: Unless you are capable of moving Mono forward, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ you should switch to .NET Core (.NET 6/7 today), as that's the future. MonoGame users reported their success like https://community.monogame.net/t/net-core-steam/13324/5